# swift(Xcode7)でスマホアプリを開発していますが

Tags: swift

ランキングデータをクラウドで管理したいのですが
できれば無料のクラウドでデータを保管し１〜１０位のデータを（かんたん、むずかしい、超むずかしい）別に更新するようなプログラムを考えています。
サーバーデータ取得→ローカルデータと比較→ローカルデータ上位の場合更新
の手順で比較的実装が簡単なものをご存知な方おられましたら教えていただきたく思います。

追記
現在swiftで簡単なゲームアプリを作成しています、ゲーム開始時の時間を設定し
成功したらその所要時間をサーバーのデータと比較し時間が短ければ更新し、大きければ破棄
し、ランキングを表示するということを実現するためにデータをサーバーに保管したいと考えておりました。

GameKitはiOS Developer Programへの登録しなくてもデータ更新のテストはできるのでしょうか？

追記２
appC cloudでデータを管理しようとしましたがアクセスした時に下記のようなエラーが発生しておりましたので、エラー確認をしているところです
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Comment: GameKitでLeaderboardを使用する場合、事前にアプリの申請が必要です。アプリを申請するには、iOS Developer Program（現Apple Developer Program）の登録が必要になります。

Answer (score 1):

単純にクラウドでランキングを管理したいだけであれば、GameKitの利用をおすすめします。

GKScoreを使ってスコアの登録、GKLeaderboardでランキングの取得などを行えます。難易度別にランキングを分けるのも簡単にできます。もちろん無料です。詳しくは、以下のURLなどを参考にしてください。

【ios7版】GameCenterのランキング表示、スコア送信を実装する - Qiita  
http://qiita.com/s0hno/items/accf11c311e037c92302

Comment: 回答いただきましてありがとうございました、GameKitを利用してみようと思います。